# Handling of stop words in simple_query_string query in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following mapping:

```
PUT idx_test
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "en_stop_filter": {
          "type": "stop",
          "stopwords": "_english_"
        },
        "en_stem_filter": {
          "name": "minimal_english",
          "type": "stemmer"
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "en_analyzer": {
          "filter": [
            "icu_folding",
            "icu_normalizer",
            "en_stop_filter",
            "en_stem_filter"
          ],
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "icu_tokenizer"
        },
        "zh_cn_analyzer": {
          "filter": [
            "icu_folding",
            "icu_normalizer",
            "smartcn_word"
          ],
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "smartcn_sentence"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "job_titles": {
        "type": "nested",
        "include_in_root": true,
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "job_title-en": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "en_analyzer"
          },
          "job_title-zh_cn": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "zh_cn_analyzer"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
POST idx_test/_doc/1
{
  "job_titles": [{"job_title-en": "chief of staff"}]
}
```

I expect the following query to find that document, but it doesn't:

```
GET idx_test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "simple_query_string": {
      "query": "chief of staff",
      "fields": [
        "job_titles.job_title-en",
        "job_titles.job_title-zh_cn"
      ],
      "default_operator": "and",
      "flags": "NOT|OR|PHRASE|WHITESPACE"
    }
  }
}
```

Elasticsearch's explanation why, is this:

```
(
    +(job_titles.job_title-zh_cn:chief job_titles.job_title-en:chief) 
    +job_titles.job_title-zh_cn:of
    +(job_titles.job_title-zh_cn:staff job_titles.job_title-en:staff)
)
```

So, apparently since `of` is an English stop word, it's removed from the lucene query, but in a way that breaks its logic.
If I search only in the English field like this:

```
GET idx_test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "simple_query_string": {
      "query": "chief of staff",
      "fields": [
        "job_titles.job_title-en"
      ],
      "default_operator": "and",
      "flags": "NOT|OR|PHRASE|WHITESPACE"
    }
  }
}
```

then the document is found as expected.

Is there any way to achieve what I need?
Essentially to find `chief of staff` in any of the fields (`job_title-en` or `job_title-zh_cn`)

Answer (score 0):

You can have the same logic using match phrase + should query.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "job_titles.job_title-en": "chief of staff"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "job_titles.job_title-zh_cn": "chief of staff"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I realized my question was probably not clear enough. I edited it now with a full example to illustrate the problem.

Comment: You use the "and" operator and thus requires that the values exist for this field Job_Titles.job_title-zh_cn. As there is no data in this field the condition will never be true.
If you change to or or choose to use a should + match-phrase will succeed.

Comment: But the logic I want is this:
I want ALL words to match in ANY of the languages. 
I.e. "chief of staff" should match because both "chief" and "staff" are found and "of" should be ignored as a stop-word.

Comment: Field Job_Titles.job_title-zh_cn does not have the value "chief of staff". You are doing a search in two fields, one has it but the other doesn't.

Your problem is not stopwords but the fields.

Comment: `job_titles.job_title-zh_cn` does not have it, but `job_titles.job_title-en` does. So it should match because ALL words are found in ANY of the fields. For example if I search for "chief staff", it will match. It is the presence of "of" that messes up the logic of the query.